# SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn - Add to availability group automatically

Tags: sql-server, failovercluster

I just got Sql Server 2012 AlwaysOn up and running.  Everything is working as planned.  However, in my production environment, we have applications that create new databases for us.  I then have to manually add these new databases to an Availability Group.  Is there a way to:

1. Have each new DB automatically added to the right group at the time it is created, or
2. Run a script periodically that will add any database not already in a group to a group

Thanks!

Scott

Comment: Can you not just have the applications run `ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP` after they create the database?

Comment: I'm not sure.  That sounds like exactly what I need.  I'll try it out and report back.  Thanks.